# Table Cell Highlight using a brighter color than standard classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table which uses some of the standard built in classes to color the table cells, e.g:

```
<td class="text-center success">
```

I've been asked to make these brighter, e.g. make this a brighter green. I'm not sure the best way to go about making this change. I don't want to edit the "success" class colour so need to define a brighter green but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: use different class with bright color then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td class="text-center success brighter-green">
```

**CSS**

```
.brighter-green {
   background-color: #2ECC71; /* For background color change */
   color: #2ECC71; /* For text color change */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the config.json from here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Or you can specifically and manually change your needed stuff from bootstrap Less Source or the SASS Source . You can get those from here

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

add an addclass to the required element

```html
<td class="text-center success custom-success">
```

```css
.custom-success{color:/*custom-color*/}
```